# Why isn's this QuickSort with randomized pivot working right?

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

For some reason if I use end or mid pivot, the algorithm works properly but if I used a randomized pivot using Math.random(), the results show up wrong and different each time.

```
function quick_sort(A, start, end) {
  if (start < end) {
    var pIndex = partition(A, start, end);
    quick_sort(A, start, pIndex - 1);
    quick_sort(A, pIndex + 1, end);
  }
}

function partition(A, start, end) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * end + 1);
  swap(A, randomIndex, end);
  var pivot = A[end];
  var pIndex = start;

  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    if (A[i] <= pivot) {
      swap(A, pIndex, i);
      pIndex++;
    }
  }
  swap(A,end, pIndex);
  return pIndex;
}

function swap(A, i, j) {
  var tmp = A[i];
  A[i] = A[j];
  A[j] = tmp;
}

var A = [12,-3, -123, 0, 11, 1, 2, 6, 4];
console.log(A);
quick_sort(A,0, A.length-1);
console.log(A);
```

Output

```
~ node test.js
[ 12, -3, -123, 0, 11, 1, 2, 6, 4 ]
[ -123, -3, 0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 11, 12 ]
~ node test.js
[ 12, -3, -123, 0, 11, 1, 2, 6, 4 ]
[ -123, 4, 0, 6, -3, 1, 2, 11, 12 ]
```

Comment: OT: drop the random index, just use `end` as your pivot-index. *(btw, shouldn't `pIndex` be `end`, not `start`?)* If the Array is shuffled, then `end` is as good as any other index, and you skipped 1 swap-operation. If the Array is already sorted, let's say `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, and you pick the 5 as your pivot, then your first swap does this `[0,1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,5]`, and now you have to swap the 5 and the 9 step by step back to their positions, whereas if you use `end` as your pivot-index, you'll only have no swapping at all.

Comment: @Thomas I did use end as pivot index before. Choosing a random pivot minimizes the chance that you will encounter worst-case O(n^2). Always choosing first or last would cause worst-case performance for nearly-sorted or nearly-reverse-sorted data).  pIndex shouldn't be end since we want to compare every element to pivot from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * end + 1);
```

Because you're selecting a pivot in `[1 ... end]` without taking the start index into account. (The start index can be anywhere in the array when the call `quick_sort(A, pIndex + 1, end)` is processed.)

It should be:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(start + Math.random() * (end - start + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks! Missed that part